# How to parse random HTML pages with Apache Tika (and XPath)

Tags: java, html, apache-tika

I'm new to Tika and stuggling to understand it.
What I want to achieve is extracting the link's href of a HTML page (which can be any webpage).

For trial version, I just tried to extract the links as such (or even just the first) using XPath. But I can never get it right and the handler is always empty.
(In this example, I've removed the `XHTML:` namspace bits because otherwise I had a SAX error).

The code example is below. Thanks so much for any help :)

```
XPathParser xhtmlParser = new XPathParser ("xhtml", XHTMLContentHandler.XHTML);
org.apache.tika.sax.xpath.Matcher anchorLinkContentMatcher = xhtmlParser.parse("//body//a");
ContentHandler handler = new MatchingContentHandler(
    new ToXMLContentHandler(), anchorLinkContentMatcher);

HtmlParser parser = new HtmlParser();
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
ParseContext pcontext      = new ParseContext();
try {
    parser.parse(urlContentStream, handler, metadata,pcontext);
    System.out.println(handler);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
....
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found an answer (at least to get something working, even if not yet final version, I got something from the handler).
The answer is at [java tika how to convert html to plain text retaining specific element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64644334/java-tika-how-to-convert-html-to-plain-text-retaining-specific-element)