# Trying to get attribute value with Apache Tika and XPath

Tags: java, xpath, attributes, apache-tika

I have tried many different XPath values and just don't understand why I can't retrieve what I want with Apache Tika.
I want to retrieve the href attribute value of links on random webpages. I managed to find out how to extract the content inside the  tags but trying to get the attribute values always returns empty.
What am I doing wrong?!
Here is my code below,
Thanks a lot

```
XPathParser  xhtmlParser = new XPathParser ("xhtml", XHTMLContentHandler.XHTML);
Matcher anchorLinkContentMatcher = xhtmlParser.parse("//xhtml:a/@xhtml:href/text()");
ContentHandler handler = new MatchingContentHandler(
    new ToHTMLContentHandler(), anchorLinkContentMatcher);
HtmlParser parser = new HtmlParser();
ParseContext pcontext = new ParseContext();
    
try {
    parser.parse(urlContentStream, handler, new Metadata(),pcontext);
    System.out.println(handler);
}
catch (Exception e)
{....}
```

I have tried these different XPaths:

```
//xhtml:a/@xhtml:href
//xhtml:a/@href/text()
//xhtml:a/@href
//@xhtml:href/text()
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there... you will need:

```
//xhtml:a/@href
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've made a mistake in writing the question (in the other XPaths I had tried). Edited the question.
However //xhtml:a/@href still returns empty content and I just can't understand why...
I think it's a problem with how I use the Tika library but I can't understand why what seems to be a valid XPath doesn't work ...

Comment: For tika code maybe see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64796279/3710053

Comment: I think I'll need to implement the parser as they do. But that makes NO sense at all. I don't understand why my attribute isn't retrieved and the Tika examples are useless. I have spent hours trying to do something that I think should work... and I don't even get any indications from the API to say why it doesn't. 
That's really frustrating.

Thanks for the suggestion at least it will help to do something else (although I'm still totally not understanding why such a simple thing doesn't work..)